# EventLoopScheduler raises method in delay

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I am using m_eventLoopScheduler.SchedulePeriodic with 30 hz cycle.
Some times I get the method called after much longer time (even 2 secodons) and not 33ms.
What is the problem and how can I fix it?

```
EventLoopScheduler elp = new EventLoopScheduler();
elp.SchedulePeriodic(sendMsg, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(33)); 
.
.
.
private void sendMsg(){...}
```

I have noticed that ThreadPool.GetAvailableThread() is decreases, so it looks like threads are allocated which takes time. ThreadPool.SetMinThreads() didn't help

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: Can you post code that demonstrates the issue? Otherwise we can't confirm that we have a solution for you.

Comment: Do you have some long running tasks that deplete the thread pool?

Comment: No. ThreadPool.GetAvilableThreads() return 65000. I did see that on a delay that the number decreases with 5 threads